# python handling DictReader missing keys

Tags: python, csv

This script is working fine, until I hit a cell that is empty:

```
import csv,time,string,os,requests
dw = "\\\\network\\folder\\btc.csv"

inv_fields = ["id", "rsl", "number", "GP%"]

with open(dw) as infile, open("c:\\upload\\log.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, inv_fields, extrasaction="ignore")
    r = (dict((k, v.strip()) for k, v in row.items() if v) for row in r)

    wtr = csv.writer( outfile )    
    wtr.writerow(["id", "resale", "number", "percentage"])
    for i, row in enumerate(r, start=1):
        row['id'] = i
        row['GP%'] = row['GP%'].replace("%","")
        w.writerow(row)

print "file successfully saved"
```

The script is failing on this line:

```
row['GP%'] = row['GP%'].replace("%","")
```

and by adding `print i` to the loop I can see it is failing on the line of the .csv file where this input value is blank.  How do I take cells with no value into this equation?

The python error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backlog.py", line 80, in <module>
    row['GP%'] = row['GP%'].replace("%","")
KeyError: 'GP%'
```

Comment: By failing you mean error? `replace` would not raise an error if the string is not found even in a blank string

Comment: you can check whether row is empty, if it is use `continue` to skip the line

Comment: @haifzhan the entire row is not empty - just this field.

Comment: The fact that you're replacing with an empty value is not the cause of your error. If you actually read the error message, you'd see that its raised by the fact that `GP%` is not a valid key for your `dict`

Comment: @m_callens correct - I see that now.  I'll update the question title to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if key `'GP%'` is the in the `row` dictionary before attempting to update its value. If it isn't you could assign a default value so the entry related to that `id` is blank in the output file:

```
for i, row in enumerate(r, start=1):
    row['id'] = i
    if 'GP%' in row:
         row['GP%'] = row['GP%'].replace('%','')
    else:
         row['GP%'] = ''
    w.writerow(row)
```

Or use the `get` method of `row` to set the default value:

```
for i, row in enumerate(r, start=1):
    row['id'] = i
    row['GP%'] = row.get('GP%', '').replace('%','')
    w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: This worked like a charm.  I learn something new about python everyday :)  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `"GP%" in row` to check whether `GP%` exist in row or not.

Alternatively, you can catch the exception:

```
try:
    row['GP%'] = row['GP%'].replace("%","")
except KeyError as ke:
    print "Error:{0}, row info:{1}".format(ke, row)
```